# Conditional Format a column based on rest of rows in that column

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm trying to conditional format Column B based on if rows C thru X have the word OPEN in them or not.

Comment: 1: do you mean " COLUMNS C thru X"?    2: remember to say what you have tried so far - StackOverflow isnt a "we write a solution for you" site. 3: is the word "OPEN" all that is in the cell, or is it between other text (eg "OPEN" vs "site is open between 9 and 5") ?

Answer (score 1):

@user3616725 makes some very relevant points in the comment but I am guessing `OPEN` fills a cell or does not count and that anywhere in C through X would be the trigger, so please try:

```
=countif(B1:X1,"OPEN")>0
```

for Custom formula is in Format, Conditional formatting... with formatting of your choice applied to Range `B:B`.